# Making child div half size of parent

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div & a child div on it.I want the child to have half width & half height of the parent div.I can't use any particular value (eg:500px) or any viewpoint units (vh & vw) / percentage dimensions.So is there any method to inherit half of the dimensions of the parent div ?

Comment: percentage dimensions?

Comment: Can't use % dimensions or viewpoint units,i know the result can be made with those units.But i just want to know if there is any method to inherit half dimensions from parent.

Comment: why can't you use percentage units? thats how you get an abstract value such as half

Comment: @Brian Dillingham ,Dear friend,i know this simple result can be achieved with % dimensions.But i just wanna know if it is possible to capture the same with any other methods to inherit the parents half dimension.

Comment: the answer is percentages if you are using CSS, you otherwise will have to look into a Javascript solution to perform calculations on the elements height and width and then divide those values in half to produce the child elements dimensions. The described Javascript approach is not inline with how CSS works.

Comment: @Ajith, I updated my answer to include a Javascript approach

Comment: @BrianDillingham Yeah it's fine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer is using percentages of parent's dimensions as the child width & height if you are using CSS

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

   <div class="child"></div>

</div>
```

**Javascript Solution**

You can otherwise divide the parent height and width in half and set it as the child dimensions..

```js
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0];

var child = document.getElementsByClassName("child")[0];

child.style.width = parent.offsetWidth / 2 + "px";

child.style.height = parent.offsetHeight / 2 + "px";
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

   <div class="child"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: what if the parent has two children? then 50% no longer works (neither does 100%)

Answer (score 0):

Use width:50% and height:50%. It will use 50% of the corresponding parent property.